# Re-arrange an HTML table with jQuery based on a given array of row IDs

Tags: jquery, sorting, html-table, jquery-ui-sortable

I have an HTML table in which each data row has a unique `id` attribute. I am writing a script that polls a server for data and uses the results it gets to re-sort the table. From the server, I receive an array like this:

```
var order_arr = [6, 4, 2, 1, 5, 3]
```

Which I want to use to visually re-sort some table data like this:

```
<tr id="user-1">...</tr>
<tr id="user-2">...</tr>
<tr id="user-3">...</tr>
<tr id="user-4">...</tr>
<tr id="user-5">...</tr>
<tr id="user-6">...</tr>
```

So that it appears to the user like this:

```
<tr id="user-6">...</tr>
<tr id="user-4">...</tr>
<tr id="user-2">...</tr>
<tr id="user-1">...</tr>
<tr id="user-5">...</tr>
<tr id="user-3">...</tr>
```

I wrote some [jQuery code on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hans/9fW6P/1/) to do this, but I don't know if it's the best technique. It fetches the array of `<tr>` elements and sorts them based on the corresponding index of each row's ID. It ends with a `.html()` call that just replaces the whole table body content.

So.. tl;dr:

1. Is [this code](http://jsfiddle.net/hans/9fW6P/1/) the best way to visually
   re-sort an HTML table given an array
   holding the desired order of row
   IDs?
2. How can I make this animated? I
   was thinking I could write this as a
   CSS hack instead, in which each
   table row has an absolute position
   and I could just run `.animate()`
   after calculating which position
   each row should hold. Thoughts vs.
   my current code?

Comment: Does the table actually need to be sorted in the dom or just visually sorted?

Comment: It could be just visually sorted, that's fine. That's what I was thinking with my CSS animation idea. Sorry, I realize now that explaining it that way might've given the wrong message.

Comment: Here's my CSS sort idea: http://jsfiddle.net/hans/6qVf5/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution I could find which kept the original functionality and added animation was with CSS. Here's the relevant JS:

```
function sort(order_arr) {
    var top = 0;    
    $.each(order_arr, function(idx, val) {
        var el = $('tbody tr#user-' + val);

        el.animate({
            position: 'absolute',
            top: top + 'px'
        }, 400);
        top += el.outerHeight();
    });
}
```

[Demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hans/6qVf5/3/)